# Перевернуть float в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как перевернуть вещественное число в python? Например введём число 123.956
И как сделать так чтобы на выход мы получили число 956.123?

Comment: `float -> str -> split -> [1].[0] -> float`

Comment: Извините, а не могли бы вы написать сам код? Как пример

Answer (score 5):

Раз уж тут стали приводить код, то более питоняче будет сделать так:

```
n = 123.956
print(float('.'.join(reversed(str(n).split('.')))))
```

Comment: у вас и у MaxU просто какой-то вагон знаний, вы не люди, вы сверхчеловеки) Апплодирую вам обоим стоя!

Comment: некоторые заигрываются с питонячестью и делают длину строки 80+. Но эт не к вам) а в воздух и согласие с @zolars

Answer (score 4):

Вот готовый код:

```py
n = 123.956

a = str(n).split(".")[::-1]

text = a[0] + "." + a[1]

n = float(text)

print(n)
```

Comment: 1000 благодарностей

Comment: @Fofan235 только ответы не забывайте отмечать правильными)

Comment: @Fofan235  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: [::-1] совсем не нужно.

Comment: @Эникейщик необязательно, так скажем) я понимаю что можно сделать так: ```text = a[1] + "." + a[0]```

Comment: ну да, именно. Просто лишняя операция получается

Answer (score 4):

Я новичок. Получилось так.

```py
a = 123.456

b = str(a).split('.')

c = float(b[1] + '.' + b[0])

print(c)
# 456.123
```